# What is a custom collection?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generic-collections

A Group of objects. However i am having confusion in the following case.

A sample class

```
class A
{
     public string Foo{get; set;}
}

class A_list
{
     public A[] list;
     public A_list(A[] _list)
     {
        list = new A[_list.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Length; i++)
        {
            list[i] = _list[i];
        }
    }
}

static void Main(String[] args)
{
    A[] names = new A[3]
        {
            new A{Foo="some"},
            new A{Foo="another"},
            new A{Foo="one"}
        };

    A_list just_an_object = new A_list(names);
 }
```

Which of the above is a custom collection the array or the object that holds array as a field or are both custom collections.

Comment: An array is not a "custom collection" according to my definition. But what is yours?

Comment: I typically reserve the term "custom collection" for when I roll my own class that _completely hides_ access to some underlying collection (essentially implements one of the `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `IList`, etc. interfaces or just exposes public members for accessing the data) but otherwise is just a data structure that is _not_ one of the built-in ones provided by the BCL.

Comment: Your naming convention is making me crazy :D It's like python puke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describing a collection as a "group of objects" is technically right but also a bit too reductive. A better question would be "what's a useful collection?", where the "useful" brings you to asking yourself "how do I need to use it"?

Now, the Array field in A_List is definitely a collection (but not a "custom" one), while your `A_List` is (arguably) a collection, but is it a useful one?

A collection is a group of *generally related* objects that you put together in order to generalize some operation on all of them. The ways you may want to *use* the collection are many, but the most common ones have been pretty much standardized in many programming languages.
For instance, in order for a collection to be "useful" you generally need at least to be able to read its elements in a forward-only loop from the first to the last.
Your A_List does not provide this directly. You could easily add custom methods to do so, but you could go a step ahead and implement an existing interface.

If you implemented [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) on A_List you would not only be able to iterate through it, but could also use your A_List interchangeably with other collections in a lot of existing code that expects a `IEnumerable`. For example:

```
class A_list : IEnumerable<A>
{
            // ... your other code

    public IEnumerator<A> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<A>)list).GetEnumerator();
    }


    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

would allow you to do this in your `main`:

```
foreach(var a in just_an_object)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Foo);
}
```

Or you could use it with Linq:

```
var numbered=just_an_object.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0,3),(a,b) => b.ToString() + a.Foo);
```

Now numbered is a `IEnumerable<String>` with three values (0some, 1another, 2one), but this is unimportant; the important bit is that (by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`) just_an_object could be used with a Linq method that works in the same way with an Array or a List or most other "standard" collections.
And also, note that neither `foreach` nor `Zip` needed to know that your `list` field is an `Array` and not a `List<A>` or a [red-black tree you implemented yourself](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8287/Red-Black-Trees-in-C), so you may want to make it `private`.

There are other things,besides iterating through it, that you may want to do with a collection. Adding or removing elements, providing a indexer (so that you can access the n-th element with `just_an_object[n]` ). As with IEnumerable, there are interfaces that enable you to implement them in a "standardized" way (look for ICollection and IList).

And then there are the "custom" aspects. The ones that made you decide that you needed your custom collection instead of directly using Array or List that already do all these things for you out-of-the-box...

Comment: I have been trying to understand the use of Ienumerable in practical code and this question was asked in that context. You just helped me a great deal in that regard. Thaaaaaank You.....

Comment: @WinCoder you're welcome, that's what we're here for... :) Glad I've been of help